# Android Kernel - Access sensor provided by proprietary blob

Tags: android, kernel, sensors, proximity

I'm looking for help on how to access a sensor that is only provided through a proprietary blob.  There's been  bit of conversation on xda about this.  However I haven't seen a resolution.  Someone had mentioned possibly being to connect through a socket to do so...  But I'm unsure what that would even mean.

Typically,  the calls would simply exist in the kernel driver for it.  However,  it doesn't get compiled...  Its prebuilt. Unless there's a way for me to force building it that I'm unaware of.

Specifically,  the sensor I'm trying to access is the  proximity sensor on a Nexus 6 (shamu).

Kernel source here: https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm.git/+/android-msm-shamu-3.10-marshmallow

Since this would be done from within a kernel module, the android sensor stack/Hal wouldn't be an option as far as I understand it.  I assume this isn't the first device that needs to access select sensors like this so I'm hoping an option already exists.

Thanks for any help that can be offered.

Comment: First you need to clarify if the specific unnamed "blob" in question is an actual kernel driver module .ko, a firmware or configuration downloaded to the sensor, or a userspace daemon.  Next you need to specify what you are trying to do with it.  Note that even a binary module (or entire binary-only kernel) may be using standard interface mechanisms which can be patched to log operations, giving you insight more readily than something like opening the device and connecting a logic analyzer might.

Comment: I'm not positive which of the proprietary files/firmware/blobs is providing the interface. There is a daemon "sensors.qcom" which is likely providing the interface with android. Of all the processes running, that seems most likely. However, running it as a foreground app provides no console output.

What I'm trying to do is simply check the status of the sensor, either the far or near state, in order to prevent a wake_gestures driver from being activated while the sensor is in the near state. 

The sensor shows as invensencse proximity in Elixir2, if that helps any.